# Session doesn't save data for different routes in express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, session

I have a login system that supposed to save user login into a session.
my back-end is Nodejs(express) and my front-end is Reactjs(with redux).
I'm using axios to send username and password to the back-end. my data get evaluated and user ID get saved into a session. so far so good but if I send a request to another route the user session will be gone.
I looked at some similar problems but got nothing. Here is my code:

This is my express-session

```
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 259200000, httpOnly: true}
}));
```

This is my axios request

> Note: I already set base url for url: "signin", the request is going
> to http://localhost:5000/signin

```
axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "signin",
            withCredentials: false,
            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json"
            },
            data:{
                "username": /*username*/`,
                "password": `/*password*/``
            }
          }).then(res => {

            if(res.status === 200){

                if(res.data.status){
                    dispatch({type: "LOGGED_IN"})       // just changes the state{authenticated : true}
                }else{
                    dispatch({type: "NOT_LOGGED_IN"})  // just changes the state{authenticated : false}
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

In signin route, after my username and password get evaluated I save user ID into session:

```
req.session.user = user._id
next()
```

In the next middleware I still have req.session.user.

I have an API for checking the user session

```
if(req.session.user){
    res.send(true);
}else{
    res.send(false);
}
```

If I make a request to that after login, I get false

> When I login and make the request with postman it returns true but with axios I get false

my axios request to that API is :

```
axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "checklogin",
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      }).then(res => {

        if(res.status === 200){
            if(res.data){
                dispatch({type: "LOGGED_IN"})
            }else{
                dispatch({type: "NOT_LOGGED_IN"})
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. I set withCredentials to false because when it was true I was keep getting CORS error. If my origins (in cors module setting ) be equal to "*" credentials is not allowed so I changed my origin to my front-end domain and set credentials to true (in cors module setting) and now I'm getting true response.